# MySQL update 1st Table using the 2nd Table with computation

Tags: mysql

Hello and Good Morning.

I have 2 Tables and it looks like this.

`Table: receiving`

[image]

and `Table: purchorder`

[image]

and here is my question.

How can I update the column `ReflectedQty` using the column `QtyPack` and `QtyStan` of `purchorder` where column `RInumber`=`RINo`.

Pls take note that the column `QtyStan` of purchorder will / 100

Here is the output I need.

[image]

TYSM for future help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update receiving r
join purchorder p
on r.RInumber = p.RINo
set r.ReflectedQty = r.ReflectedQty - p.QtyStan - (p.QtyStan / 100)
-- where r.RINumber = 'myvalue'
```

My Edited Code

```
update receiving r
join purchorder p
on P.RInumber = r.RINo
set p.ReflectedQty = Format(p.ReflectedQty - r.QtyPack - (r.QtyStan / 100),2) where RINumber = 'RI861RMA'
```

Comment: Sir I want to use criteria like `where RINumber = 'myvalue'`

Comment: @NyxAssasin Add `where` clause will be fine, check my answer again please.

Comment: I will try this sir kinly wait :)

Comment: It worked sir but i changed some part especially on the aliases. TYSM, for help :)

Comment: @NyxAssasin Great and Thanks.

Comment: This code would not be possible without your idea TYSSSSSM

Comment: Sir it has a minor error the computation turns to be negative if value are the same

Comment: @NyxAssasin What do you mean about 'value are the same'?

Comment: lets say `ReflectedQty = 10.00` and `QtyPack = 10.00` and `QtyStan = 0.00` the computations turns to `-10.00` on the `ReflectedQty`

Comment: What if you try this : `select Format(10 - 10 - (0 / 100),2)`? @NyxAssasin